# Pictures of sewing machines with date

Tags: data-request, historical, industry, photographs

I am looking for pictures of [sewing machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sewing_machine).

It is important that each picture has a date associated (date of production of the machine, not date of the picture), so that I can sort the machines chronologically.

Wikicommons-usable license preferred.

The [Wikicommons category](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Sewing_machines) does not have date sub-categories, and most pictures don't mention a date, and those who do do it in prose, which is difficult to use in a script.

Comment: Are you going to London any time soon? http://www.visitlondon.com/things-to-do/place/116129-london-sewing-machine-museum If so, bring your camera.